# Image Preloading for animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a banner at the top of some of my webpages. The banner is static until the user clicks on the play button which kick starts the animation.

The animation is one long horizontal image that just rolls around and iv got it overlapping perfectly.

But what I want to happen is to have a smaller alternative image to load first, while the large image loads behind then once it is loaded to replace the original small image so there is no delay on the page...

How do I go about this?

This is my js to get the banner to play on click.

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{
    var mwbannerfull = $( '#mwbannerfull' );
    var playing = false;
    var playarrow = $( '.playarrow' );
    var speed = 0.145;
    var totalDistance = 4350;
    playarrow.click(function()
    {
        if (playing)
            pause();
        else
            play();

        playing = !playing
        playarrow.toggleClass('playing');
    });

    function play() 
    {
        var distance = parseInt(mwbannerfull.css('left'), 10) * -1;
        if (isNaN(distance)) distance = 0;
        distance = totalDistance - distance;
        var time = distance / speed;
        mwbannerfull.animate({left: '-' + totalDistance + 'px'}, time, 'linear', function()
        {
            $(this).css(
            {
                left: 0
            });
            play();
        });
    }
    function pause() 
    {
        mwbannerfull.stop();
    }
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="mwprobanner">
    <a href="#!" class="playarrow">
        <i class="icon-play"></i>
        <i class="icon-pause"></i>
    </a>
    <div id="mwbannerfull"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

data-l will store your large image

```
<img data-l='https://www.google.com.hk/images/srpr/logo11w.png' src='http://www.microsoft.com/global/learning/en-us/PublishingImages/ms-logo-site-share.png' />
```

```
function startLoading() {

    $("img").each(function () {
        var _this = $(this);
        var src = $(this).attr('data-l');
        if (src != "") {
            var tmp = $(new Image());
            //When loaded
            tmp.one('load', function () {
                _this.replaceWith(tmp);
            });
            tmp.attr('src', src);
        }
    });

}
```

Image will start loading after 2 seconds.

```
setTimeout(function(){
    startLoading();
},2000);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/netorz04/